# How to use foreach in Splunk to divide two columns

Tags: splunk

I have a series of columns in Splunk.

A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3

I want columns C1=A1/B1, C2=A2/B2...

I am doing `foreach A* [eval C<<MATCHSTR>>='<<FIELD>>'/B<<MATCHSTR>>]` but this does not work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `foreach`.  Simple `eval` commands should do it for a limited number of fields.

```
| eval C1=A1/B1,C2=A2/B2, C3=A3/B3
```

For an indefinite number of fields, we can revisit `foreach` once you explain "does not work".  :-)

Comment: It is for an indefinite number of fields. When I say it does not work, it does not give the output expected i.e new columns are not created with the value.

Comment: This worked for me.
`| makeresults 
| eval A1=1, A2=2, A3=3, B1=4, B2=5, B3=6 
| foreach A* 
    [ eval C<<MATCHSTR>>=<<FIELD>>/B<<MATCHSTR>>] 
| table A* B* C*`

Comment: I tried that but it did not work for me. And for the field to work I have to give something like this '<<FIELD>>'.

Comment: My `foreach` command works with and without single quotes.  It doesn't work, however, if the value of A or B is not a a number.  Can you share more details about your use case?

Comment: The table is actually a result of a time chart grouped by one of the fields and hence there will be multiple columns/fields with fields like A1, A2, A3, B1, B2 , B3 where 1,2,3 are fields values on which it is grouped on.

Comment: Sample output from the `timechart` command would be helpful in determining why `foreach` is not working as expected.